# What are the delimiters for protobuf messages?

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

What are the delimiters for protobuf messages? I'm working with serialized messages. I would like to know if the messages begins with $$__$$ and ends with the same sign.

Comment: After some discussion and thinking the decision fell to add headers to the messages to solve the problem. Thnx everybody for the input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For top level messages (i.e. separate calls to serialize): there literally isn't one. Unless you add your own framing, messages actively bleed into each-other, as the deserializer will (by default) just read to the end of a stream. So: if you have blindly concatenated multiple objects without your own framing protocol: you now have problems.

For the internals of messages, there are two ways of encoding sub-objects - length prefix and groups. Groups are largely deprecated, and the encoding of sub-objects is ambiguous in that it is also the same markers that describe strings, blobs (bytes), and "packed arrays". You probably don't want to try to handle that.

So: it sounds like you need to add your own framing protocol, in which case the answer will be : whatever your framing protocol defines. Just remember that protobuf is binary, so you cannot rely on any byte sequence as a sentinel  / terminator. You should ideally use a length prefix approach instead.

Comment: Is this the case with the protobuf 2 and 3 compiler ? Do you know by any chance? I'm geting what you are trying to explain., it is definitively something I have to reconsider i a bigger picture.

Comment: @MarkoBencik the binary protocol is identical regardless of which DSL (proto2 / proto3) or compiler or other tools you use. The binary protocol itself: does not terminate outermost messages.

Answer (score 6):

(In addition to existing answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52338751/5128464), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52341449/5128464))

Common framing method for protocol buffers is to prepend a [varint](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints) before actual protobuf message.

The implementation is already part of the protobuf library, e.g.:

- for java: [MessageLite.writeDelimitedTo()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite#writeDelimitedTo-java.io.OutputStream-), [Parser.parseDelimitedFrom()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Parser#parseDelimitedFrom-java.io.InputStream-)
- for C: methods in header [google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.h](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.cc) (e.g. `SerializeDelimitedToFileDescriptor()`)

Good luck with your project!

EDIT> [The official reference](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming) states that:

> If you want to write multiple messages to a single file or stream, it is up to you to keep track of where one message ends and the next begins. The Protocol Buffer wire format is not self-delimiting, so protocol buffer parsers cannot determine where a message ends on their own. The easiest way to solve this problem is to write the size of each message before you write the message itself. When you read the messages back in, you read the size, then read the bytes into a separate buffer, then parse from that buffer. (If you want to avoid copying bytes to a separate buffer, check out the CodedInputStream class (in both C++ and Java) which can be told to limit reads to a certain number of bytes.)

Comment: This approach works just fine for when the receiver gets the bytestream from the very beginning. I'm not overly familiar with protobuf's byte strean, but I'm not sure that it works if the receiver gets the bytestream part way through as it might be difficult to distinguish between the delimiting varint and a varint message, etc.

Comment: @bazza I understand your point, but I am afraid that there is no such requirement in the question. Protobuf encoding is definitely not self-synchronizing. If need arises there are framing protocols which has that property (e.g. [COBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Overhead_Byte_Stuffing)). My bet is that in most cases the stream integrity is guaranteed by an upper layer. Feel free to post a better answer thought....

Comment: No, I have no better answer, your's is excellent and most certainly answers the question! I just wish Protobuf did introduce self synchronisation, it would be even more useful then. Thanks for the tip on COBS, I've previously spun my own (I've generally got away with it), but it's nice to have a library for it instead.

Answer (score 2):

The Protocol Buffer wire format is not self-delimiting, so protocol buffer parsers cannot determine where a message ends on their own. The easiest way to solve this problem is to write the size of each message before you write the message itself. When you read the messages back in, you read the size, then read the bytes into a separate buffer, then parse from that buffer.